# Understanding Asymptotic Equipartition Property

Tags: digital-communications, channelcoding, information-theory, random, probability

I have some problems in understanding the precise meaning of the Asymptotic Equipartition Property, related to a large number n of independent and identically distributed random variables (X1, X2, ..., Xn). Here an example is shown ([here](http://acts.ing.uniroma1.it/courses/comtheory/2019-2020/LectureSlides/20191025_ComTh&Eng_lecture4_english-AEP.pdf) you may find the complete material):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I do not understand the precise difference between the sentences:

- "Clearly, it is not true that all 2n sequences of length n have the same
  probability."
- "One might be able, however, to predict the probability of the sequence that is actually observed. The question is: what is the probability p(X1,X2,...,Xn) of the outcomes X1,X2,..., Xn, where X1,X2,..., Xn are i.i.d. according to p(x)"
- "the typical set has probability close to 1, all the elements of the
  typical set have same probability"

Then I read this sentence, which increases the confusion in my mind.
[image]

Comment: Have you read "Element of Information Theory", Cover & Thomas ? Especially its chapter 3 Asymptotic Equipartition Property (2nd edition) ? IMHO, it contains the answer for all of your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentences you've mentioned in your question all have a quite different meaning. Let me try to explain them one by one:

> Clearly, it is not true that all $2^n$ sequences of length $n$ have the same probability.

This refers to the example of a sequence of binary i.i.d. random variables. If $p(1)\neq p(0)$ then it is clear that sequences with different numbers of ones and zeros must have different probabilities, i.e., not all sequences have the same probability.

> One might be able, however, to predict the probability of the sequence that is actually observed. The question is: what is the probability $p(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ of the outcomes $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n$, where $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. according to $p(x)$?

This question is answered by the asymptotic equipartition property (AEP). It turns out that the *typical* sequences do have approximately the same probability as $n$ gets large, namely $2^{-nH}$.

> The typical set has probability close to 1, all the elements of the typical set have [the] same probability.

That's also what the AEP says. As mentioned before, the typical sequences have approximately the same probability, and the aggregate probability of the typical set approaches $1$ as $n$ gets large.

Finally, the statement

> The concept of a typical set is generally different from that of a high probability set.

is indeed confusing. What is meant is the fact that there can exist individual sequences that are not part of the typical set but which have a higher probability than the typical sequences. Still, the aggregate probability of the typical set approaches $1$ for increasing $n$, and there are too few atypical sequences with high probability to have any significance.